# Define a number line in R

Tags: r, numbers

I'm trying to make a number line like this in R:

```
" (-1)n - 1/n : n ∈ ℕ and 0 < n "
```

Because I want R to find the infimum of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean (-1)^n -1/n ? Because -n -1/n would just give you an infimum of -infinity.

Although for my answer it does not matter. To make a line up to given n.lim, I would do:

```
nlim<-10000
n <- 1:nlim
```

> myline <- (-1)^n-1/n

Which gives for the first 15 elements:

> myline[1:15]

```
 [1] -2.0000000  0.5000000 -1.3333333  0.7500000 -1.2000000  0.8333333
 [7] -1.1428571  0.8750000 -1.1111111  0.9000000 -1.0909091  0.9166667
[13] -1.0769231  0.9285714 -1.0666667
```

Hope this is what you were after.